# Finding the number of entities (e.g. restaurants) in one dataframe around points in a different dataframe (e.g. hotels) (coordinates counting problem)

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates, geopandas, shapely

For a project, we are trying to count (and name) the number of points in one dataframe that are around points in another dataframe with a certain radius given. We tried a lot, but upon verifying our solution by manually counting the points in Tableau have not reached a satisfying solution. We are fairly close though.
We have two dataframes.
One dataframe has around 70k rows and 50 columns with a unique hotel ID, latitude, longitude, name and different information on the hotels (e.g. "has_desk" true/false etc.).
The other has around 25k rows and 9 columns, with a unique establishment ID, latitude, longitude, name, amenity type (e.g. "restaurant" vs "bar") and other information such as cuisine and vegan_available etc.

Due to the size of the datasets, a nested loop that calculates for every hotel the distance to every restaurant etc. seems out of the question.
It also seems like a good idea to use a hexagon instead of a real circle around the hotels for computing reasons.

Input:

```
radius_in_m = 200
```

df_hotels:

```
    id  lat lon name
0   1   50.600840   -1.194608   Downtown Hotel
1   2   50.602031   -10.193503  Hotel 2
2   3   50.599579   -10.196028  Hotel 3
```

df_poi:

```
    id  lat         lon         name                    amenity
0   451152  51.600840   -0.194608   King of Prussia         restaurant
1   451153  51.602031   -0.193503   Central Restaurant  restaurant
2   451154  51.599579   -0.196028   The Catcher in the Rye  bar
```

Wanted outcome:
df_hotels_new:

```
    id  lat lon name      num_restaurants       restaurants_list     num_bar     bars_list  
0   1   50.600840   -1.194608   Downtown Hotel        2         [451152, 451153]      0       []
1   2   50.602031   -10.193503  Hotel 2               0         []                    1       [451154]
2   3   50.599579   -10.196028  Hotel 3               0         []                    0       []
```

In the example, the first two restaurants would be within 200m of the first hotel. That count is added to the new column. A list with the IDs of the two restaurants counted is added to yet another column. The third one is a bar and thus not counted for restaurants. Note the lat/long are completely fictitious in the example and not actually within the 200m radius.

The most successful try so far was this, but it mostly overestimates the number of restaurants. It also does not list the restaurants/bars/etc in another column, but we have gotten that to work. Through that, we were able to see that the radius seems to be "slightly" (around 1.5x) larger than specified and maybe also shifted a little. Could this be a rounding or map projection error?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import pyproj
import math

# Define the conversion factor from meters to degrees based on the latitude
def meters_to_degrees(meters, latitude):
    proj_meters = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:3857")  # meters
    proj_latlon = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:4326")  # degrees
    transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(proj_meters, proj_latlon, always_xy=True)
    lon, lat = transformer.transform(meters, 0)
    lat_dist_per_deg = 111132.954 - 559.822 * math.cos(2 * math.radians(latitude)) + 1.175 * math.cos(4 * math.radians(latitude))
    lon_dist_per_deg = 111412.84 * math.cos(math.radians(latitude))
    lat_degrees = meters / lat_dist_per_deg
    lon_degrees = meters / lon_dist_per_deg
    return lat_degrees, lon_degrees




# Convert the hotels DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame with a Point geometry column
hotels_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_hotels, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_hotels["longitude"], df_hotels["latitude"]))

# Convert the poi/restaurant DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame with a Point geometry column
poi_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_poi, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_poi["longitude"], df_poi["latitude"]))

# Create an R-tree spatial index for the df_poi GeoDataFrame
df_poi_sindex = poi_geo.sindex

# Define the radius of the search in meters
radius_meters = 200

# Loop through each row in hotels_geo
for index, row in hotels_geo.iterrows():
    # Convert the radius from meters to degrees based on the latitude
    lat, lon = row["latitude"], row["longitude"]
    lat_deg, lon_deg = meters_to_degrees(radius_meters, lat)
    
    # Use the R-tree spatial index to find the df_poi rows within the search radius
    candidate_indices = list(df_poi_sindex.intersection(row.geometry.buffer(lon_deg).bounds))

    # Filter the street_test rows to only those within the search radius
    candidate_rows = poi_geo.iloc[candidate_indices]

    # Group the candidate rows by amenity and count the occurrences
    counts = candidate_rows.groupby("amenity").size().to_dict()

    # Add the counts as new columns in the df_hotels DataFrame
    for amenity_type, count in counts.items():
        df_hotels.at[index, amenity_type] = count

    # Print progress
    if index % 10000 == 0:
        print(f"Processed {index} rows")

# Replace NaN values with 0
airbnb_test.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate this in an efficient way in bulk you could try [geopandas.sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html#geopandas.sjoin_nearest.).

Regarding the accuracy, geopandas only calculates planar distances, so with data in lat-long you will always get significant errors. It sounds like you ar not working on world scale data so maybe it is possible to reproject your data to a projected (Equidistant?) coordinate system to get better accuracy.

Sample code to use sjoin_nearest:

```
countries = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
radius_meters = 200

cities_w_country_data = geopandas.sjoin_nearest(cities, countries, distance_col="distance", max_distance=radius_meters)
```